# RESTful call does not work from Windows 8.1 Mobile app (VS 2013), but works otherwise

Tags: c#, rest, mobile, windows-8.1, win-universal-app

I am using this code to call a simple REST service. It works from ASP.NET app, XAML app, but does not work from a Windows Moble App. I am using VS-2013 (update 4) on a Windows 8.1 OS. Any idea what might be wrong?

Update: This issue happens only for the Windows store app, not for phone app (I am using Univeral App to target Windows and Phone).The Phone app works fine. There must be something to be done for Windows emulator.

> "An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its
>   access permissions

```
HttpResponseMessage responseMessage;
System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://myRESTURL/url/");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));
 System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpRequestHeaders headers = client.DefaultRequestHeaders;

        try
        {
            responseMessage = await client.GetAsync("");

            if (responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                String version = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            exceptionString = e.InnerException.ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows App Emulator and Phone Emulator uses different OS settings to connect to the network. This I think is the main reason for REST call working form Phone emulator, and not working from the App emulator.

This does make sense given that the phone emulator should pretty much not depend on my machine settings, while the app can. But I am not sure what specific settings are  used by the App emulater and Phone emulator.

Please share your findings.

Thanks!!

Comment: Also, you can get around this by using a wrapper rest service using a WebAPI project. This gets around Windoes App Simulator's limitations with using VPN

Answer (score 0):

Start by restarting your firewall service ([Source](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/e0cc1b3e-2c63-451a-abc8-8e1e66a23287/an-attempt-was-made-to-access-a-socket-in-a-way-forbidden-by-its-access-permissions?forum=w7itpronetworking))

I have seen this a couple of times when debugging a windows store app.  Simply restarting the "Windows Firewall" windows service fixed it for me just now.  I didn't even need restart the app.